# selecting a table row which contains a tr with a certain text with jQuery using .filter()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, dom, web-applications

I'm trying to select the row in a table which contains `one` `td` with a specific text using the `jQuery .filter()` function. My function looks like this....

```
function getBudgetRowByType(serviceTypeNum) {
        alert(serviceTypeNum);
        if (parseInt(serviceTypeNum) == 1) {
            var row = $('.bgTablePopUp > tbody > tr').filter(function () {
                $(this).children("td:contains('Instruction')");
            });
            return row;
        } else if (parseInt(serviceTypeNum) == 2) {
            var row = $('.bgTablePopUp > tbody > tr').filter(function () {
                $(this).children("td:contains('Research')");
            });
            return row;
        } else if (parseInt(serviceTypeNum) == 3) {
            var row = $('.bgTablePopUp > tbody > tr').filter(function () {
                $(this).children("td:contains('Administration')");
            });
            return row;
        } else {
            // Else nada
            return null;
        }
    }
```

the html would look something like this...

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>Instruction</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Research</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Administration</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
<td>...</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

I keep getting an undefined result and I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use `.filter` like this - (*same for other conditions*)

```
if (parseInt(serviceTypeNum) == 1) {
            var row = $('.bgTablePopUp > tbody > tr > td').filter(function () {
                    return $.trim($(this).text()) === "Instruction";
            }).closest('tr');
            return row;
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand why my original code doesn't work, though. Won't the DOM query return true if it finds such a child? I mean if I added the return keyword...

Comment: @MassStrike No, you need to explicitly return true or false. you can refer to api for more info `--->` http://api.jquery.com/filter/

Answer (score 0):

Here is a POJS way of doing it (IE9+), otherwise requires [`Array.prototype.filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) support (for which there are shims for), [`document.querySelectorsAll`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll) (but you could use other DOM methods to get the `tr` elements, or again their are shims available, you can event use jquery to select them) and [`Node.textContent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) (again shims are available, or just walk the DOM and collect the text nodes). I think it is good to see alternatives, and you have already selected an answer for your [`jQuery.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) issue. You may also find the use of a [`switch`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch) statement better for what you are doing.

Javascript

```
function contains(elements, string) {
    return Array.prototype.filter.call(elements, function (tr) {
        return tr.textContent.indexOf(string) !== -1;
    });
}

function getBudgetRowByType(serviceTypeNum) {
    var row = null,
        selector = "table tr";

    switch (parseInt(serviceTypeNum)) {
        case 1:
            row = contains(document.querySelectorAll(selector), "Instruction");
            break;
        case 2:
            row = contains(document.querySelectorAll(selector), "Research");
            break;
        case 3:
            row = contains(document.querySelectorAll(selector), "Administration");
            break;
        default:
    }

    return row;
}

console.log(getBudgetRowByType("1"));
console.log(getBudgetRowByType("2"));
console.log(getBudgetRowByType("3"));
console.log(getBudgetRowByType("4"));
```

On [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Xotic750/jSzAk/)

Comment: Oh this is a cool solution, I'm going to have to read through this a bit more closely, there's some things I haven't seen before. Thanks man!